# Foreign Key constraint for two tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have 4 Tables :

1) SuperParent --> idsuperparent(PK)

2) ParentA     --> idparentA(PK) , idsuperparent(FK)

3) ParentB     --> idparentB(pk), idsuperparent(FK)

4) Child      ---> idchild(PK) , idparentA(FK) ,idparentB(Fk)

I want to make sure that In child table entry is valid if and only if "idsuperparent(FK)" for both parentA and parentB is same, any suggestion how can I add such constraint without adding any extra field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can use triggers for this extra check purpose.

Create before insert and before update triggers.

Use `new.idparentA` and `new.idparentB` to access new value of parent ids to load superparent ids. Then just compare the superparent ids and signal an error if they differ.

It would be something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_child
BEFORE INSERT ON Child
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE superParentA INT;
  DECLARE superParentB INT;
  SET @superParentA = ..;
  SET @superParentB = ...;
  IF (superParentA <> superParentB) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Super parrents are different!';
  END IF
END
```

Comment: @VivekGhule Glad it worked. You can accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Check constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) (required MySQL starting with version 8.0.16)

Comment: since the "idsuperparent" is not present in child table seems unable to use the CHECK Constraint,isn't it?

Comment: sorry, I did not read the question carefully. COuld you help to post the full schema?

Comment: np, can do using trigger. Thanks